# Move widget down so it overlays on top of main panel

Tags: css, r, shiny

Is there a way to move a widget down (selectInput) so that it overlays the main panel? I have been trying to modify the position of the widget, but I end up pushing the main panel down too. What I want is to move the position of the widget so that it is overlaying the top of the chart in the main panel.

I add a minimal reprex

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
#tags$li(div(style="variable1: margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; padding-top:0px;")),
fluidRow(
column(4,
div(style="variable1: margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; padding-top:0px;",
    selectInput("variable1", "Variable 1:",selected="Petal.Length",
choices=names(iris[1:4])))),
fluidRow(column(4,
       div(style="variable2: margin-left:0px; margin-top:0px; padding-top:0px;",
selectInput("variable2", "Variable 2:",selected="Sepal.Length",
choices=names(iris[1:4])))))),

mainPanel(width=12,plotOutput("abcPlot")))



server <- function(input, output) {



output$abcPlot <- renderPlot({
print(ggplot(iris,aes_string(input$variable1, input$variable2))+geom_smooth())

})

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could adjust the position CSS property of the widget by setting to absolute and adjust the top property to move the widget down.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           div(style="position: absolute; top: 10px; margin-left:100px; margin-top:0px; padding-top:0px;z-index: 1;",
               selectInput("variable1", "Variable 1:", selected = "Petal.Length",
                           choices = names(iris)[1:4]))),
    fluidRow(
      column(4,
             div(style="position: absolute; top: 10px; margin-left:300px; margin-top:0px; padding-top:0px;z-index: 1;",
                 selectInput("variable2", "Variable 2:", selected = "Sepal.Length",
                             choices = names(iris)[1:4]))))),
  mainPanel(width = 12, plotOutput("abcPlot"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$abcPlot <- renderPlot({
    print(ggplot(iris, aes_string(input$variable1, input$variable2)) + geom_smooth())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]